# Is に okay in 「田中さんはビデオゲームに遊んでいます」?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

I have a question with the follow sentence:

> 田中さんはビデオゲーム**に**遊んでいます

Is the particle に okay?

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Language on StackExchange!  Please see our Help section for questions that are [on-topic](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  This borders on a direct translation request (which are *off*-topic), so you might want to refine the question.  Maybe you can include why you chose to use `に`, any alternatives you might have considered, etc.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but what I think the question might be: if one simply plays a game, I think `を` might be the appropriate particle, but in some cases, like online multiplayer games, or ones with sufficient immersive reality, one might consider themselves as being *in* the game. So maybe in that case, might `に` or `には` work? Could changing the particle be a quick shorthand way to convey that my sense of agency is not *toward* the game but *within* the game? If that's what's being asked, then it would be a very interesting question (to me, anyway).

Comment: My vote is it's a particle question, not a translation question.  Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Kaji, I think the problem is not so much whether it's translation versus particles, but even as a particle question, the asker doesn't demonstrate any effort on their side, so we don't know why this particular usage confuses them. We don't know the context, the source, or what the user thinks the meaning might be, or anything like that. It's hard to provide a specific answer if we don't know if the asker has even a basic understanding of particles.

Comment: When 遊ぶ means "to study around contries or insist your theory there", it can take locative に.

Comment: @DaveMG Thank you for the answer. mmm what I want to say is "I'm playing a video game" but I'm not sure if the verb 遊ぶ is transitive or intransitive. I understand that the particle を must be used with transitive verbs, but I believe that in this case it is not necessary.

Comment: 岩波国語辞典 lists 遊ぶ as 自動詞(intransitive verb). For "I'm playing a video game", I'd say ゲームをしています, using the verb する.

Comment: @Choko (岩波国語辞典) do you know the name in English or it's only in Japanese?

Comment: [岩波国語辞典]{いわなみこくごじてん} is a monolingual Japanese dictionary (="Iwanani Japanese Dictionary", maybe?)... Just a sec

Comment: 遊ぶ on Wiktionary. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B6 They say it's intransitive.

Answer (score 7):

> Is the particle に okay?

I'm afraid not. I think you can say it like this:

> 田中さんはビデオゲーム**で**遊んでいます。

This `で` is like "with", as in the instrumental (`具格{ぐかく}`) case, rather than "in" or "on".

Or you can also say:

> 田中さんはビデオゲームをしています。
>   田中さんはビデオゲームをして遊んでいます。

Comment: Just an additional question, as per my comment on the question, how would you express "I played *in* the game"? As in, a person had an avatar in a virtual reality game, and then inside the game they played around. So it's not that they play the game, but instead, *within* the game they play. Would `ゲームには遊んでいます` work?

Comment: @Dave M G: "I played in the game" would be ゲームの中で遊んだ.

Comment: @DaveMG Thank you for the edit. You'd use (物)で遊ぶ to mean "play with (物)", and (場所)で遊ぶ to mean "play in (場所)" too. eg: 部屋で遊ぶ(play in a room), オモチャで遊ぶ(play with a toy). When I hear ゲームで遊ぶ I think it means "play (with) a game", so I would use ゲームの中で遊ぶ to mean "play in a game". (But I'd use ゲームで for "in a game" when it's not ambiguous/confusing: ゲームで敵を倒した, メタルギアでワニを食べた, バイオハザードでルイスに撃たれた etc.)

Comment: I believe that in this case the particle で　is not the appropriate because the video game is an idea rather than a psychical object, but if we talk about the interface (xbox, play, pc..) that are being used the particle で it's ok. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation. `:)`.